# Pandas: How to find the first valid column among a series of columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, feature-extraction

I have a dataset of different sections of a race in a pandas dataframe from which I need to calculate certain features. It looks something like this:

```
id         distance     timeto1000m    timeto800m    timeto600m   timeto400m   timeto200m    timetoFinish
1          1400m        10             21            30           39           50            60    
2          1200m        0              19            31           42           49            57   
3          1800m        0              0             0            38           49            62   
4          1000m        0              0             29           40           48            61
```

So, what I need to do is for each row find the first `timetoXXm` column that is non-zero and the correspoding distance `XX`. For instance, for `id=1` that would be 1000m, for `id=3` that would be 400m etc.

I can do this with a series of `if..elif..else` conditions but was wondering if there is a better way of doing this kind of lookup in pandas/numpy?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this, first filter the cols of interest and take a slice, then call [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) on the cols of interest to return the columns where the boolean condition is met:

```
In [11]:
df_slice = df.ix[:,df.columns.str.startswith('time')]
df_slice[df_slice!=0].idxmin(axis=1)

Out[11]:
0    timeto1000m
1     timeto800m
2     timeto400m
3     timeto600m
dtype: object

In [15]:
df['first_valid'] = df_slice[df_slice!=0].idxmin(axis=1)
df[['id','first_valid']]

Out[15]:
   id  first_valid
0   1  timeto1000m
1   2   timeto800m
2   3   timeto400m
3   4   timeto600m
```

Answer (score 1):

use `idxmax(1)`

```
df.set_index(['id', 'distance']).ne(0).idxmax(1)

id  distance
1   1400m       timeto1000m
2   1200m        timeto800m
3   1800m        timeto400m
4   1000m        timeto600m
dtype: object
```